# Parse JSONString and then iterate over the array in handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have data like this :

```
{ "data" : [
 {
   "query": "Hello",
   "response": "asad"
 },
{
"query": "Tell Weather dale",
"response": "[{\"datetime\":\"2024-01-26\",\"tempmax\":21.5,\"tempmin\":7,\"temp\":14,\"humidity\":59.2,\"precip\":0,\"precipprob\":0,\"windspeed\":5.8,\"cloudcover\":61.6,\"conditions\":\"Partially cloudy\"},{\"datetime\":\"2024-01-27\",\"tempmax\":23.2,\"tempmin\":11.2,\"temp\":16.3,\"humidity\":38.2,\"precip\":0,\"precipprob\":0,\"windspeed\":9.4,\"cloudcover\":32.5,\"conditions\":\"Partially cloudy\"},{\"datetime\":\"2024-01-28\",\"tempmax\":24,\"tempmin\":11.7,\"temp\":17.2,\"humidity\":39.9,\"precip\":0,\"precipprob\":0,\"windspeed\":10.4,\"cloudcover\":54.9,\"conditions\":\"Partially cloudy\"},{\"datetime\":\"2024-01-29\",\"tempmax\":25,\"tempmin\":12.6,\"temp\":18.2,\"humidity\":42.1,\"precip\":0,\"precipprob\":0,\"windspeed\":9.7,\"cloudcover\":41.3,\"conditions\":\"Partially cloudy\"},{\"datetime\":\"2024-01-30\",\"tempmax\":25.3,\"tempmin\":13.8,\"temp\":18.8,\"humidity\":48.2,\"precip\":0,\"precipprob\":0,\"windspeed\":6.1,\"cloudcover\":66.5,\"conditions\":\"Partially cloudy\"},{\"datetime\":\"2024-01-31\",\"tempmax\":26.2,\"tempmin\":14.6,\"temp\":19.5,\"humidity\":48.4,\"precip\":0,\"precipprob\":0,\"windspeed\":9.4,\"cloudcover\":14.9,\"conditions\":\"Clear\"}]"
}
] }
```

wherein the response could either be a normal string or a JSONString. I want to parse the json string, iterate over the array and show the individual keys like datetime, temp etc.

I'm able to parse the JSON but I'm unable to then iterate over it handlebars template.

Can someone please help me on how the template and the helper functions should look like?

Comment: I would advise parsing JSON _prior_ to sending these data to your Handlebars template function. Is that an option? Otherwise, you would need to create a custom helper to parse the JSON. The next question would be: Is the JSON always a consistent structure?

Comment: This is what is coming from the backend team and cannot be altered. I made a helper function to parse the JSON which parses it but I run into errors for example if I do 

{{#each JSONparse message.response }} {{ this.datetime}}{{/each}}

I get into errors, also this messes up when it's just a string and not a parsable JSON strig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I feel I need to say is that your team is doing something wrong if there is a property of the response object whose value can be either a string *or* a stringified JSON of arbitrarily-shaped data.

It my opinion that it is the back-end response that needs to worked on.

However, for the fun of the challenge, let's think about how we could solve this in the template.

One thing that is unclear to me is that when the `response` is stringified JSON, if that JSON will always have the same structure or not. For simplicity, I am going to assume that it will always be an array of objects.

As you stated in the comments, a `JSON.parse` is going to error when given input that is not stringified JSON. Therefore, we would need to use a `try/catch` to catch that error and just return the `response` unparsed, as we will assume it is a string.

We could create a [Block Helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html) that would allow us to define the template to be used when `response` *can* be JSON parsed. Our helper will just return the unaltered `response` when it can't be JSON parsed.

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(`
{{#each data}}
  <p>Query: {{query}}</p>
  <p>Response:</p>
  {{#parseResponse response}}
    {{#each this}}
      <ul>
        {{#each this}}
          <li>{{@key}}: {{this}}</li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    {{/each}}
  {{/parseResponse}}
{{/each}}
`);

Handlebars.registerHelper('parseResponse', function (response, options) {
  try {
    return options.fn(JSON.parse(response));
  } catch (err) {
    // console.error(err);
    // We will ignore the error and return `response` below
  }
  
  return response;
});

const data = {
  "data": [{
      "query": "Hello",
      "response": "asad"
    },
    {
      "query": "Tell Weather dale",
      "response": "[{\"datetime\":\"2024-01-26\",\"tempmax\":21.5,\"tempmin\":7,\"temp\":14,\"humidity\":59.2,\"precip\":0,\"precipprob\":0,\"windspeed\":5.8,\"cloudcover\":61.6,\"conditions\":\"Partially cloudy\"},{\"datetime\":\"2024-01-27\",\"tempmax\":23.2,\"tempmin\":11.2,\"temp\":16.3,\"humidity\":38.2,\"precip\":0,\"precipprob\":0,\"windspeed\":9.4,\"cloudcover\":32.5,\"conditions\":\"Partially cloudy\"},{\"datetime\":\"2024-01-28\",\"tempmax\":24,\"tempmin\":11.7,\"temp\":17.2,\"humidity\":39.9,\"precip\":0,\"precipprob\":0,\"windspeed\":10.4,\"cloudcover\":54.9,\"conditions\":\"Partially cloudy\"},{\"datetime\":\"2024-01-29\",\"tempmax\":25,\"tempmin\":12.6,\"temp\":18.2,\"humidity\":42.1,\"precip\":0,\"precipprob\":0,\"windspeed\":9.7,\"cloudcover\":41.3,\"conditions\":\"Partially cloudy\"},{\"datetime\":\"2024-01-30\",\"tempmax\":25.3,\"tempmin\":13.8,\"temp\":18.8,\"humidity\":48.2,\"precip\":0,\"precipprob\":0,\"windspeed\":6.1,\"cloudcover\":66.5,\"conditions\":\"Partially cloudy\"},{\"datetime\":\"2024-01-31\",\"tempmax\":26.2,\"tempmin\":14.6,\"temp\":19.5,\"humidity\":48.4,\"precip\":0,\"precipprob\":0,\"windspeed\":9.4,\"cloudcover\":14.9,\"conditions\":\"Clear\"}]"
    }
  ]
};

const output = template(data);

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.8/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this comment, I was able to solve it myself but thank you for the detailed answer. I followed a very similar approach too.